# How to set directory folder name into a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, file-upload, multer

I am trying to upload files in the backend and I am successfully done it but the problem is I am uploading the files in a folder. So I need to parse the files so I need to define the folder name so that the file can be parsed. How can I define the folder name?

Here is the code, The folder name is `uploads`, but when I try to parse the file it says `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/uploads/undefined-1647961709285.xlsx'`

```
const worksheetsArray = xlsx.parse('/uploads/' + filename);
```

Comment: Your question is unclear: does the file `/uploads/undefined-1647961709285.xlsx` exist?

Comment: yes it is exist into the upload folder

Comment: from NodeJS point of view, the file does not exist when it tries to access it, which is why you get an ENOENT error